# Getting Cassandra to listen on 9042 properly

Tags: cassandra

I simply want to get a single Cassandra node running and connect from a remote server.

```
lsof -i :9042
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    22089 cassandra  137u  IPv4  80564      0t0  TCP cassansra.sucks.com:9042 (LISTEN)
```

on the Cassandra server:

```
sudo nodetool status 
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  202.28 KiB  256          100.0%            6e485a3c-7e0f-452c-8545-77380f21daa0  rack1
```

What I want is 9042 to listen on an IP address.  I have the below in the cassandra.yaml file:

```
  rpc_address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I am using Cassandra 3.x.

Comment: How do you try to connect? You should be able to connect to port 9042 on the IP address you specified as `rpc_address`. If Cassandra binds to the hostname instead that means `rpc_address` is not set. You might be looking at the wrong `cassandra.yaml` or you have not saved your changes to the file, or made some other mistake?

Answer (score 2):

As `nodetool status` works fine.

Please check if cassandra daemon is listening native transport port ( default: 9042 ).

Execute following command if cassandra daemon is **NOT** listening native transport port :

`nodetool enablebinary`

Answer (score 0):

`-e CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS` and `-e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true` - if we set these two options, it will be able to connect the 9042 port from external machines.

Can you print the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`, so we should be able to see why the error is output. Are you using Docker? Use below details if so: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/. Even if it is not Docker, the options remains the same.

Comment: `START_RPC` enables the thrift protocol on 9160, and has nothing to do connecting via the native binary protocol on 9042.